# Insert values in 2d numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, 2d

I am stuck on this simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out, I have a diagonal array:

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
A = numpy.diag(N)
```

And I have a list of row and column indices such as this:
    B = [[1,0],[2,1],[3,2]]

I want to insert a value of 1 in A given the location from B, it helps to think of A as a 2-D matrix and B the set of coordinates I want to insert the value A in.

I tried to use the numpy.put but it doesn't seem to allow me to access a 2d array and I don't know how to think about it in a for-loop sense.

The desired answer would look like this:

```
A = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0],...,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9]]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for loop

```
for x in B:
    A[x[0],x[1]]=1

A
Out[189]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the first and the second coordinates together:

```
I, J = zip(*B)
```

or

```
I, J = numpy.transpose(B)
```

Then you can index `A` directly

```
A[I, J] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `B` a `numpy` array:

```
B = np.array(b)
```

Then just index using the first and second columns:

```
A[B[:, 0], B[:, 1]] = 1
```

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```